# Augmenting Observable.Create for F#

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I'd like to augment

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Create<TSource>(
    Func<IObserver<TSource>, Action> subscribe)
{...}
```

For use in F# so that rather than calling with a Function or Action I can just use standard F#  types i.e `IObserver -> (unit -> unit)`.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit:

Adding full example.  Not sure why `obsAction` does not work.

```
open System
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Disposables
open System.Reactive.Linq


type Observable with
  static member Create(subscribe) = 
    Observable.Create(fun observer -> Action(subscribe observer))

let obsDispose (observer:IObserver<_>) =
    let timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
    timer.Interval <- 1000.00
    let handlerTick = new Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fun sender args ->     observer.OnNext("tick"))
    let handlerElapse = new Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fun sender args -> printfn "%A" args.SignalTime)
    timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(handlerTick)
    timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(handlerElapse)
    timer.Start()
    Disposable.Empty

let obsAction (observer:IObserver<_>) =
    let timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
    timer.Interval <- 1000.00
    let handlerTick = new Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fun sender args -> observer.OnNext("tick"))
    let handlerElapse = new Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fun sender args -> printfn "%A" args.SignalTime)
    timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(handlerTick)
    timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(handlerElapse)
    timer.Start()
    let action() =
        timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(handlerTick)
        timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(handlerElapse)
        timer.Dispose()
    action

let obsOtherAction (observer:IObserver<_>) =
    let timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
    timer.Interval <- 1000.00
    let handlerTick = new Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fun sender args -> observer.OnNext("tick"))
    let handlerElapse = new Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fun sender args -> printfn "%A" args.SignalTime)
    timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(handlerTick)
    timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(handlerElapse)
    timer.Start()
    new System.Action( fun () ->
        timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(handlerTick)
        timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(handlerElapse)
        timer.Dispose())

let worksNeverStops = obsDispose |> Observable.Create |> Observable.subscribe(fun time -> printfn "Time: %A" time)
let actionWorks = obsOtherAction |> Observable.Create |> Observable.subscribe(fun time -> printfn "Time: %A" time)
let doesNotWork = obsAction |> Observable.Create |> Observable.subscribe(fun time -> printfn "Time: %A" time)
```

Comment: `let create<'TSource> (subscribe: IObserver<'TSource> -> Action) = ...`

Comment: How to go from Action to unit -> unit?

Comment: Can't you just replace Action with (unit -> unit)? Or do you mean how to interop between F# and C#?

Comment: @Christian There's a subtle problem hiding in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is an FP gotcha.

In,

```
  static member Create(subscribe) = 
    Observable.Create(fun observer -> Action(subscribe observer))
```

the type of `subscribe` is `IObserver<_> -> unit -> unit`.

Now  there's a subtle difference between `IObserver<_> -> unit -> unit` 
and `IObserver<_> -> Action` where `Action : unit -> unit`. The difference is that the former is curried, and the latter isn't.

When an observer subscribes, `subscribe observer` returns a method in to which `()` can be applied to get `unit` - your subscribe method will never actually be called until the last `()` is applied - which won't be until it un-subscribes by which point it will already be detached.

You can get over it by forcing it to not be curried:

```
let action() = ... | let action = (subscribe observer)
Action(action)
```

Further:

If you check the IL, the equivalent VB (function refs are more clearer in VB) versions for the `Invoke` for the `FastFunc` generated for

```
 static member Create(subscribe) = 
    Observable.Create(fun observer -> Action(subscribe observer))
```

is:

```
Friend Function Invoke(ByVal arg As IObserver(Of a)) As Action
    Return New Action(AddressOf New Observable-Create-Static@27-1(Of a)(Me.subscribe, arg).Invoke)
End Function
```

and for:

```
  static member Create(subscribe) = 
    Observable.Create(fun observer ->
      let action = subscribe observer
      Action(action))
```

is:

```
Friend Function Invoke(ByVal arg As IObserver(Of a)) As Action
    Return New Action(AddressOf New Observable-Create-Static@28-1(Me.subscribe.Invoke(arg)).Invoke)
End Function
```

1. `AddressOf New Closure(Me.subscribe, arg).Invoke` -> The subscribe function won't get called until the dispose action is called.
2. `AddressOf New Closure(Me.subscribe.Invoke(arg)).Invoke` -> The subscribe function actually gets called and the resulting action is returned as expected.

I hope it is now clear why the second case works, and not the first.

Comment: How did you determine this?

Comment: @Daniel Reflector to view the IL. I've edited the answer for clarity.